# What are IFR departure categories?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules, instrument-procedures, departure-sid

I'm looking at the takeoff mins and DPs for Reno/Stead (RTS.)  It lists takeoff mins for Cat A and B, Cat C and D NA:

> TAKEOFF MINIMUMS: CAT A,B only, CAT C,D NA. Rwys 8,14,  1300-2 or std.
>   with a min. climb of 400' per  NM to 6500.  Rwy 26,  1900-2 or std.
>   with a min. climb  of 410' per NM to 7200.  Rwy 32,  2300-2 or std.
>   with a  min. climb of 420' per NM to 7200.
>   ([Source](http://fr.flightaware.com/resources/airport/RTS/MIN/TAKEOFF+MINIMUMS/pdf))

What are the departure categories?  I can't find any mention of them in the instrument flying handbook.

Comment: Could be [this category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_approach_category).

Comment: @mins Actually, the smaller aircraft CAN use the DP as long as they have either the ceiling/vis and/or the climb performance; the "CAT C,D NA" means that the larger aircraft can NOT use the DP under any circumstances.

Answer (score 5):

The categories are actually approach categories that are also used for departures. From the AIM, **5−4−7. Instrument Approach Procedures**

> Aircraft approach category means a grouping of aircraft based on a
>   speed of VREF, if specified, or if VREF is not specified, 1.3 VSO at
>   the maximum certified landing weight. VREF, VSO, and the maximum
>   certified landing weight are those values as established for the
>   aircraft by the certification authority of the country of registry. A
>   pilot must use the minima corresponding to the category determined
>   during certification or higher.
>
> 1. Category A: Speed less than 91 knots.
> 2. Category B: Speed 91 knots or more but less than 121 knots.
> 3. Category C: Speed 121 knots or more but less than 141 knots.
> 4. Category D: Speed 141 knots or more but less than 166 knots.
> 5. Category E: Speed 166 knots or more.

These categories are used to determine visibility and ceiling minimums for an approach and determine the protected area for circling approaches. As you can see in the departure minimums you quoted, they are also used for departures.